# Combining variables

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, predictor

I'd like to combine several variables into one variable.  Here is some context:

Let's say I have two variables `Red.Beads` and `Blue.Beads` and each observation of each variable is a number representing the number of beads for that observation.  Say each red bead has a mass of 5 grams, and each blue bead has a mass of 1 gram.

I can a single variable representing overall bead mass for observation by doing the following:     5*Number.Red.Beads<sub>i</sub> + 1*Number.Blue.Beads<sub>i</sub>.

But, if I do not have access to the mass of each type of bead, is there a meaningful way to combine the variables to get some proxy for mass of beads present.  My initial thought was to standardize each variable (i.e. compute z-score), and then combine (i.e. z-score.Red<sub>i</sub> + z-score.Blue<sub>i</sub>).  I recognize that this approach suffers from some problems, and I wonder what other options exists for combining the variables?  In my situation, I want to combine different numbers of variables from 2 or 3 up to about 40 variables.  Thanks in advance for any thoughts.  Best Regards.

Comment: Why would a z-score help? Do you have any kind of guess as to which "beads" are heavier than others? Would the distribution of the number of beads have any relationship to the mass of the beads? (If not, then there is no better solution than just summing them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no idea about the weights of bead types, then you can't combine them meaningfully. Period.

Imagine two types of beads one with mass 1 tonn, and the other with a mass 1 mg. Unless you have some additional information about the total weight, there's no way to devise the combined variable. Of course, you always have some idea about the total weight, maybe typical values of total wight. In this case you can come up with a reasonable weights to get a combined variables.

Comment: Thanks.  I may be able to get mass categories (i.e. 0.01 - 0.1 g for Red and 0.001 to 0.01 g for Blue) for a wider range of beads than I have accurate mass information for.  I'll likely have the same problem of no information for some bead types (i.e. maybe there is no mass information for Green beads), and it means reaching out to the cantankerous bead-mass-expert community for insights...